# Get all the blobs inside sub directory inside container

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

So I'm having issues on getting the blobs inside my container - I'm able to successfully grab all the blobs inside a container, but not inside a folder in the container - How would I be able to successfully do that?

**Problem**:
I have a folder inside my container called '`big/`' - How would I be able to grab all the blobs from that folder instead of just the generic container as I'm doing below?

All help would be appreciated!

So here is the `getBlobs()` method that I have (View the image and code below):
[image]

```
/**
 * Get all blobs from container
 *
 * @param int $max
 * @return array
 */
public function getBlobs(int $max = 5000) : array
{
    // Check if a container is set
    if (!$this->containerName) {
        return [];
    }

    try {
        $blobMeta = [];
        $blobOptions = new ListBlobsOptions();

        // Set the max results at 5000 (Default: 5000)
        $blobOptions->setMaxResults($max);

        do {
            // Grab the defined container
            $blob_list = $this->connect()->listBlobs(
                $this->containerName,
                $blobOptions
            );

            var_dump($blob_list);
            die();

            // Loop through all the
            foreach ($blob_list->getBlobs() as $blob) {
                $blobMeta[] = [
                    'name' => $blob->getName(),
                    'url' => $blob->getUrl(),
                ];
            }
            $blobOptions->setContinuationToken($blob_list->getContinuationToken());

        } while ($blob_list->getContinuationToken());

        return $blobMeta;
    } catch (ServiceException $e) {
        $code = $e->getCode();
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        echo $code . ": " . $error_message . PHP_EOL;
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: How's going? Has your issue been solved?

Comment: Yes it has @StanleyGong :) - Thanks for helping out! I'll upvote the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to list blobs under a folder, you can use `ListBlobsOptions` to `setPrefix("YourFolderName/")` to do this. You can find a detailed code sample in `listBlobsSample` function at line 430 [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/samples/BlobSamples.php).